# Shared element transition image jumps down on exit transition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment, shared-element-transition

I've been searching everywhere for a cause of this problem and applied most of the solutions that I've found online but I've had no luck.

Here's the situation, I have two activities, one with a viewpager with a recyclerview inside each tab. When I click one of the items from the recyclerview it will open a modal activity that has the target transition image inside a fragment.

So the image will expand from the recyclerview item to the activity modal image

So something like this: Activity1/ViewPager/RecyclerView/Item/Image -> Activity2/Fragment/Image

It works beautifully from Activity1 to Activity2 but when the exit animation occurs the image jumps down, like half the image and lands in Activity one half an image down so it looks really clunky.

Here there are some code snippets:

**recyclerview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/product_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/bordered_image"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/default_item" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I open the activity like this:

```
val options = ActivityOptions
    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, sharedImage, sharedImage.transitionName)
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
```

This is how I handle the modal activity

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.rounded_dialog)
    window.setLayout(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
```

And inside the onCreateView of the fragment I add this

```
image.transitionName = "image_${mItem.id}"
image.loadUrl(mItem.image)
startPostponedEnterTransition()
```

And I use glide for showing the image like this

```
private fun ImageView.loadUrl(url: String) {
    val options = RequestOptions()
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .apply(
            options.transforms(
                CenterCrop(),
                RoundedCorners(150)
            )
        )
        .into(this)
}
```

This is how the image returns to the activity 1:

[image]

**EDIT:** So I've found the problem. I use a custom style for the activity dialog. In the android manifest I add this to the activity:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.Activity2"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActivityDialog"/>
```

And the style is this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActivityDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

This is somehow breaking the animation

Answer (score 0):

So I found what the problem was:

> An activity transition works like this. When you start your second activity, it is >displayed on top of your first one with a transparent background. The shared elements are >positioned the same way they are on the first activity and then animated to the correct >position specified on the second activity.
>
> In your case you are using android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" which mean the >size of the second activity's drawing area is smaller than the one from the first >activity. This explains the clipping and the no transition when clicking outside.

I changed the theme of the Activity2 to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActivityDialog" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

And added a cardview to the activity 2 layout and it works now